# Angular Datatable Sort numbers with suffix(k, Mn, Bn)

Tags: angular, datatable, angular-datatables

I am using datatable with angular 8. I need to sort the column with number having suffix as `k, Mn, Bn`.

Example:

```html
<table>
<thead>
<tr><th>Number</th><tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
<tr><td>12 Mn</td><tr>
<tr><td>1.2 k</td><tr>
<tr><td>12.2 k</td><tr>
<tr><td>555</td><tr>
<tr><td>12 Bn</td><tr>
<tr><td>33 Mn</td><tr>
<tr><td>5 Mn</td><tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

Plugin link:
https://l-lin.github.io/angular-datatables/#/getting-started

Answer (score 0):

```html
<table>
<thead>
<tr><th>Number</th><tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
<tr><td>12 Mn</td><tr>
<tr><td>1.2 k</td><tr>
<tr><td>12.2 k</td><tr>
<tr><td>555</td><tr>
<tr><td>12 Bn</td><tr>
<tr><td>33 Mn</td><tr>
<tr><td>5 Mn</td><tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

Huuuy

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).